# Magento Shipping Rates issue

Tags: magento

I am selling wine bottles in my magento shop. The customer can order as 1 bottle or a pack of 6 bottles. I have created 2 simple product for each and then created a grouped product for it. So, each wine is added as grouped product with 1 bottle & 6pack bottles as simple product

Now my shipping rate is configured with table rates as 
Upto 6 bottles - 5$
Upto 12 bottles - 8$
Upto 24 bottles - 10$
From 25 bottles - Free

Now when a customer would order 2times 6pack products, the shipping cost is calculated as 5$ instead of 8$

How can I get this issue fixed?

Comment: This order is one order or it is two different order. Because shipping rate is apply to whole order amount.

Comment: Try to use weight for it: 1pc + 1pc = 2pc (actually packs), but if 1pc = 6kg then weight = 12 kg.